# Completely remove magento 2 using command

Tags: magento2

How can i remove magento2 using command line?

I wants to remove database manually.

I want to get it by command line.

Please help me to solve out this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

complete uninstall magento2

> php bin/magento setup:uninstall

Please try this code.

**I hope this will work**